# When I log out, I find this error "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-knox

I am using django-rest-knox, when I logout using `knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view()`, it gives me this error:

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Note: I am using a custom user model(`AbstarctUser` and `BaseUserManager`)

Here is `serializers.py`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email','birth_date','first_name','last_name')

# there is a registerserializer too

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

and here's `views.py`:

```
class LoginView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user= serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })

class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/views/#logoutallview):

> This view accepts only a post request with an empty body. **It responds to Knox Token Authentication**. On a successful request, the token used to authenticate, and all other tokens registered to the same User account, are deleted from the system and can no longer be used to authenticate.

This means you still need to use the token you generated upon authentication with the logout endpoint.

Comment: I used knox_views.LogoutView.as_view() but in django, I don't know how to pass the token in the header, it doesn't give me the option, is there some setup to use or should I implement logout by myself?

Comment: Are you using a front-end framework? If so, just add the token you got from register/login, and then add that the same way via authorization

Comment: No I am not using front-end framework, I just access the logout as http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/
path('logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
it is just a simple task for learning so how can I manage to put the token for logging out?

Comment: How did you login and get a token?

Comment: If you are using postman, you can add the token as an authorization header with type `Token`, or for example when using curl: `curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8000/logout' --header 'Authorization: Token <your_token>'`

Comment: using the loginSerializer and loginView implemented above. In the urls.py path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='knox_login'),
when I login with email and password the response will be something like that
{
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "rana",
        "email": "rana@gmail.com",
        "birth_date": "2021-08-07",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    },
    "token": "f658f3da8c3d664e5744dd46002319e9cbc56654744b2970afc024f0b9c8407e"
}

Comment: What client did you use to hit the API? A front-end framework? How did you pass the registration details to django

Comment: I am a newbie to all of this stuff so I don't know what you mean by using a client to hit the API. However, I am using a registerSerializer (model serializer) as I have a custom AbstractUser and I am using the above RegisterApi, so to access the registration page here is the URL path('register/', views.RegisterAPI.as_view(), name='knox_register')
Does that answer your question?

Comment: Partly. I'm trying to understand how you are accessing this API and passing the parameters youve shown. Is it through a browser? If it is through a browser, you must be using some sort of form. So is that form from a django template or from javascript-based client? And since you successfully generated a token, how are you using it?

Comment: Well, I didn't know I have to use forms :'( so I think from what you are saying I either use forms or postman. and about the token I still don't use I was willing to use it to logout just to learn how to register,login and logout using django rest knox.

Comment: No not necessarily. There a lot of ways to pass it, but depending on that, I can give you an idea how to use the token. Can you tell me how you logged in with `path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='knox_login')`. What did you use to pass the username and password to this endpoint?

Comment: Ok how about this. Run django locally. After you get your token, run this on a terminal: `curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8000/logout' --header 'Authorization: Token f658f3da8c3d664e5744dd46002319e9cbc56654744b2970afc024f0b9c8407e'`

Comment: The logging out It works fine after using postman but in the browser, it is still the same message. Whatever thank you a lot for your help @bdbd

Comment: Yes because when doing it in the address bar of the browser, it won't let you add headers. But if you are in chrome, there are extensions that can provide functionality for this

Answer (score 0):

you have to explicitly override authentication_classes on your new logout view
or call it from Django setting

```
class MyCustomLogoutView(LogoutView)
    authentication_classes = (Your custom Authentication,)
```

or

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

class MyCustomLogoutView(LogoutView)
        authentication_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
```

or access it from Django setting directly